# Broadcast Receiver ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to listen incoming call in a background service. But its not working, in debug, `OnReceive()` is not triggered. I've searched in all topic without any help.

I though that the background service was the problem, then i moved the code in the MainActivity class but it still not working.

**Android Gradle Version : 4.1.2**

**Gradle Version : 6.6**

**API : 30**

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.StatusChecker">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StatusChecker.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".ServiceChecker"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
</application>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony">
</uses-feature>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

MainActivity (OnCreate) :

```
   ...
   // Create reciever object
   IncomingCallReceiver the_receiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();

    // Set When broadcast event will fire.
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);

    // Register new broadcast receiver
    this.registerReceiver(the_receiver, filter);
    ...
```

IncomingCallReceiver.java :

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context mContext;
private Intent mIntent;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        // TELEPHONY MANAGER class object to register one listner
        TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        //Create Listner
        PhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener();
        // Register listener for LISTEN_CALL_STATE
        tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}

private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        String callState = "UNKNOWN";
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Hey call event",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Hey call event",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Hey call event",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            
        }
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
};
}
```

Thank you for help and sorry for my English mistakes.

EDIT :

Solution found...

You just need to add the permission request in your code.

```
 String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG
    };

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            PERMISSIONS,
            PERMISSION_ALL);
```